# IOS Collection View

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm new to IOS Development,

I'm designing an interface where I want to use the collection view to place the controls as if in a grid,

For this, I'm using a collection as shown in the picture below

[image]

However, at runtime, this screen is appearing completely black:

[image]

I was expecting to see the interface I designed as in the first image. But why is the interface appearing completely black?

Comment: What is the nature of your emergency?

Comment: edited, with the question

Comment: Show the collection view data source & delegate protocol implementation, please.

Comment: if I am adding controls to the UICollectionView, do i need the data source and delegate protocol methods?

Comment: I want to use it as a grid layout to add controls

Comment: Grid layout k but you should do delegate,datasource connection to view thw collection view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default color of UIcollectionView will looks like black only if you want make it visible try to change the View color of UicollectionView and you want to make visible your grid Layout  means connect your collection view with delegate and datasource and use collection view delegate functions.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

and this is good tutorial for Uicollection view [Look at this link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/)